# make neo4j commands from terminal or shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, neo4j, command-line-interface

Is there any way to make commands to neo4j from the command line without entering the shell, in other words the equivalent of:

`mysql -u user -ppassword -e "INSERT INTO something VALUES something-else"`

I'd also like to be able to make commands from an executable script, something akin to:

`mysql -u user -ppassword << EOF
INSERT INTO something VALUES something-else;
EOF`

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: Christophe Willemsen and Dave Bennett's answers both work, the one using curl is quite intriguing, and lower level than I expected. I started using py2neo, and found that it comes with a `cypher` command that processes commands much like Christophe's and my mysql examples. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You could always use curl to post requests to the REST API.

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '{"statements" : [ { "statement" : "create (n:Node {name: \"Test\"} ) return n" } ] }' \
http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
```

Here is the [Neo4j REST API](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api.html) reference.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass arguments to the neo4j-shell command :

Execute cypher passed in the command :

```
./bin/neo4j-shell -c 'match(n:Page) RETURN count(n);'
```

Or execute a cypher script file :

```
./bin/neo4j-shell --file your-file.cql
```